# Describe this language that is generated by Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

Describe this language that is generated by a Context Free Grammar

$S \to SS$

$S \to XXX$

$X \to aX \mid Xa \mid b$

Answer (score 0):

Let's work backward. $X$ can generate any number of $a$'s with exactly one $b$ hidden in between. $S\to XXX$ turns every single $S$ into three $X$'s. $S\to SS$ generates any (positive) number of $S$'s.

Do the remaining math yourself.